# Cutting Video using JAVA /JSP or Javascript at a particular point

Tags: java, jsp, video

I am creating a website where user can watch video. And I want to give functionality to user where he can cut some part of video and save to its drive (doing it on Local Host). I have designed video player consisting of two buttons (start point and endpoint). When user clicks on start and endpoint button, it should cut that particular part only.

Questions-

1. How to store start and end points [i.e time ] in variable when user click   on  those buttons??
2. Is it possible to do above things using javascript?

Given code cuts video into equal parts. I want to cut video from 1.15 min to 2.30 min only.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SplitVideoFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Despicable Me 2 - Trailer (HD) - YouTube.mp4");//File read from Source folder to Split.
        if (file.exists()) {

        String videoFileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")); // Name of the videoFile without extension
        File splitFile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Videos_Split/"+ videoFileName);//Destination folder to save.
        if (!splitFile.exists()) {
            splitFile.mkdirs();
            System.out.println("Directory Created -> "+ splitFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        int i = 01;// Files count starts from 1
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        String videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ String.format("%02d", i) +"_"+ file.getName();// Location to save the files which are Split from the original file.
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
        System.out.println("File Created Location: "+ videoFile);
        int totalPartsToSplit = 20;// Total files to split.
        int splitSize = inputStream.available() / totalPartsToSplit;
        int streamSize = 0;
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {

            if (splitSize == streamSize) {
                if (i != totalPartsToSplit) {
                    i++;
                    String fileCount = String.format("%02d", i); // output will be 1 is 01, 2 is 02
                    videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileCount +"_"+ file.getName();
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                    System.out.println("File Created Location: "+ videoFile);
                    streamSize = 0;
                }
            }
            outputStream.write(read);
            streamSize++;
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Total files Split ->"+ totalPartsToSplit);
    } else {
        System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath() +" File Not Found.");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do anything* if you try hard enough. Learn about the subjects and come here when you encounter specific problems. Be advised you that for displaying video in browser, HTML5 or Flash are considered the best technologies for making it look good and performant.

Comment: I have code which cuts entire video into equal parts. but i want only specific part of video. I dont know how to take start and end points from video.